# Can TerminateThread terminate a thread from another process?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, winapi

In my Windows service application I may resort to calling [TerminateThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686717(v=vs.85).aspx) API on some of the threads in my process. (Note that I do so only as a last resort measure when a thread fails to quit in a "normal fashion" using signaling mechanism and thread synchronization techniques.) What I've noticed in the event log submitted by a customer is that very rarely `TerminateThread` may throw the `STATUS_INVALID_THREAD` exception, which happens only when that API is called on a thread belonging to a `threadpool`.

Since I know for sure that none of my threads are started from a threadpool, the thread that my call to `TerminateThread` attempts to close must be coming from another process. This could happen only due to a race condition where my thread handle is closed first and then is passed again to the `TerminateThread` API while the OS reuses it for some other thread in another process.

So my question is, since my service is running with sufficiently high privileges (as `localService`) can `TerminateThread` API in this situation inadvertently terminate some thread belonging to another process? And if yes, how can I prevent this (apart from finding the race-condition, that I'm doing now)?

Comment: Are you opening other processes?

Comment: @usr: Yes. It may open other processes.

Comment: If thread fails to quit by normal means then it is good. A defect in your code manifested itself. Track it down and fix, do not use TerminateThread.

Comment: The only way to wind up with a handle to a threadpool thread from another process is to call OpenThread.  If you don't call OpenThread, then this isn't your problem.  If you do, you can put a copy of each such handle into a table.  Before calling TerminateThread, search the table to see if the handle you're using is there; if it is, you've got the wrong handle.

Comment: You're making at least two unsafe assumptions, by the way: firstly, there's no guarantee that the only possible cause for the STATUS_INVALID_THREAD exception is that you're trying to terminate a threadpool thread; secondly, even though your code doesn't use the threadpool, there may still be threadpool threads in your process, started automatically by the operating system or by third-party software.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Care to elaborate your "unsafe assumptions"? Otherwise it's just a rhetoric. (Maybe start an answer of your own.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston: I do not call `OpenThread` on those handles, for sure. I take them from `CreateThread` and the only other APIs they are used for are: `WaitForSingleObject`, `CloseHandle` and  `TerminateThread`.

Comment: You said you thought the handles were being reused; the only way for a reused handle to refer to a thread in another process is if you are calling OpenThread somewhere in your code.  (Otherwise, where would the handle to the remote thread come from?)

Comment: @HarryJohnston: I'm asking myself that same question. Could it just match numerically to the one opened by another process?

Comment: No, handles are specific to each individual process.  Bit of a security nightmare otherwise!

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Yeah, that's what I thought. I guess I have to un-mark the post below as an answer. I just tried and you're right, it won't work without calling `OpenThread` or `DuplicateHandle` calls.

Comment: The issue I have then, is why did I get that `STATUS_INVALID_THREAD` exception when calling `TerminateThread`. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: My best guess hasn't changed since the previous question; Windows (for whatever reason) has created at least one threadpool thread in your process, and the handle to that thread has the same numerical value as the one you're trying to use after it was closed.  My second best guess is that you are actually targeting the right thread, but that it is in an unexpected state (*not* related to threadpooling) which makes it impossible to kill.  Since you can't reproduce the issue, the only way to tell which is to add code that double-checks the identity of the handle, as discussed previously.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Thanks. Your response seems to be the answer to my question. Although you gave me more questions than I expected.

Comment: @c00000fd You got `STATUS_INVALID_THREAD` because the thread was in a state in which the implementation was unable to terminate it, such as an uninterruptible wait. Unpredictable results occur if you call `TerminateThread` on a thread not known to be in a state where asynchronous termination is safe. This is one of them. From the [horse's mouth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686717%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), "*You should call TerminateThread only if you know exactly what the target thread is doing*".

Answer (score 3):

Let's let the docs speak for themselves:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686717(v=vs.85).aspx

Do not use `TerminateThread()`:

> `TerminateThread` is a dangerous function that should only be used in the most extreme cases. You should call `TerminateThread` only if you know exactly what the target thread is doing, and you control all of the code that the target thread could possibly be running at the time of the termination. For example, `TerminateThread` can result in the following problems:
>   [...]

You can terminate any thread, as long as you have a handle with sufficient privileges:

> A thread cannot protect itself against `TerminateThread`, other than by controlling access to its handles. **The thread handle returned by the `CreateThread` and `CreateProcess` functions has `THREAD_TERMINATE` access, so any caller holding one of these handles can terminate your thread.**

Comment: So the answer is `yes`? I'm also assuming that there's no `THREAD_TERMINATE_IN_ANOTHER_PROCESS` privilege, correct?

Comment: yes. If you have a handle with that privilege, it does not matter whether you are in a different process. The disclaimer about it being unsafe (just about guaranteed a but) still applies.

Answer (score 3):

> Note that I do so only as a last resort measure when a thread fails to quit in a "normal fashion" using signaling mechanism and thread synchronization techniques.

That is a case where you *cannot* call TerminateThread. You can only call TerminateThread if you have precise control over the thread you are terminating and its full cooperation. If the thread fails to quit in the normal fashion, then you have lost control over the thread, the very opposite of the required conditions under which you can call TerminateThread.

If a process has lost control over one of its threads, the process cannot be saved. This is a fundamental property of threads -- they do not provide isolation of anything but flow control.

Comment: So what shall I do there instead?

Comment: @c00000fd It's hard to say without understanding your full outer problem, but probably isolate the unsafe code in its own process. (Assuming the code can't be fixed.) Threads must cooperate inside a process or the process is lost.

Comment: In that case your answer sounds like philosophy to me.

Comment: ,@c00000fd Any sane code that uses threads has to understand the philosophy of threads, specifically that they cooperate inside a process and that they are not isolated from each other. What if the thread you are terminating holds a lock in the memory allocation library, has broken some of its invariants, and is about to restore them?

Comment: The same can btw be extended to any processes sharing resources in any way needing cooperation.

Comment: @c00000fd you have to fix your defective code that causes threads to hang. There are no other ways to achieve working programs.

Comment: @Deduplicator Right, but the difference is that threads share things that cannot be isolated or protected, like the memory allocator. If you have, say, two processes that share a file, you can code each process so that it can sanely handle, or even repair, corruption in the file. You can't handle corruption in a memory allocator.

Comment: @ÖöTiib: OK. I got it. Didn't I say that at the end of my question. It just always amazes me that there's always some smarta*% that tries to teach me how to code in multithreaded environment when I'm asking a totally different thing.

Comment: @c00000fd You are trying to make something work that *cannot* be made to work. The documentation says so and painful experience says so.

Comment: @c00000fd I just terminate the whole program when it fails such sanity checks. It is defective and can cause whatever other problems, TerminateThread is your attempt to hide defects from testers and users instead of fixing those.

Answer (score 1):

If you must do this you can do it like this.

All you need to start is the thread handle.

You call the first function with thread handle as input using the "undocumented" [NtQueryInformationThread()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winternl/nf-winternl-ntqueryinformationthread) function with the [ThreadQuerySetWin32StartAddress](http://ntinternals.net/UserMode/Undocumented%20Functions/NT%20Objects/Thread/THREAD_INFORMATION_CLASS.html#ThreadQuerySetWin32StartAddress) argument, you get the StartAddress of the thread.  More reading @ [NTInternals](http://ntinternals.net/UserMode/Undocumented%20Functions/NT%20Objects/Thread/NtQueryInformationThread.html).

It calls NTQueryInformationThread by function address after getting the address via GetProcAddress.  Then it calls it with the **ThreadQuerySetWin32StartAddress** argument, getting the **StartAddress** of the thread.

Then you call the second function which loops through all the threads via **CreateToolHelp32Snapshot** and compares against the supplied **StartAddress**.  It calls **TerminateThread** once it finds it.

```
enum THREADINFOCLASS
{
    ThreadQuerySetWin32StartAddress = 9,
};

typedef NTSTATUS(__stdcall * f_NtQueryInformationThread)(HANDLE, THREADINFOCLASS, void*, ULONG_PTR, ULONG_PTR*);

ULONG_PTR GetThreadStartAddress(HANDLE hThread)
{
    auto NtQueryInformationThread = reinterpret_cast<f_NtQueryInformationThread>(GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("ntdll.dll"), "NtQueryInformationThread"));
    if (!NtQueryInformationThread)
        return 0;

    ULONG_PTR ulStartAddress = 0;
    NTSTATUS Ret = NtQueryInformationThread(hThread, ThreadQuerySetWin32StartAddress, &ulStartAddress, sizeof(ULONG_PTR), nullptr);

    if (NT_FAIL(Ret))
        return 0;

    return ulStartAddress;
}


bool TerminateThreadByStartaddress(ULONG_PTR StartAddress)
{
    HANDLE hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPTHREAD, 0);
    if (hSnap == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return false;

    THREADENTRY32 TE32 = { 0 };
    TE32.dwSize = sizeof(THREADENTRY32);

    BOOL Ret = Thread32First(hSnap, &TE32);
    while (Ret)
    {
        HANDLE hTempThread = OpenThread(THREAD_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, TE32.th32ThreadID);
        if (!hTempThread)
        {
            Ret = Thread32Next(hSnap, &TE32);
            continue;
        }

        if (StartAddress == GetThreadStartAddress(hTempThread))
        {
            TerminateThread(hTempThread, 0);
            CloseHandle(hTempThread);
            CloseHandle(hSnap);
            return true;
        }

        CloseHandle(hTempThread);

        Ret = Thread32Next(hSnap, &TE32);
    }

    CloseHandle(hSnap);

    return false;
}
```

Credits to my friend Broihon, I didn't write this code but have used it before.

Comment: dude, are you upvoting your own answers L)

Comment: It certainly looks that way.  I think I have a fan

Comment: :) anyway, thanks. I'll have to try it. I asked this question 2 yrs ago. Now I need to re-read wtf I was asking there :)

Answer (score 0):

Use undocumented `NTSYSAPI NTSTATUS NTAPI NtTerminateThread(IN HANDLE ThreadHandle, IN NTSTATUS ExitStatus);` from http://undocumented.ntinternals.net where ThreadHandle is result from [OpenThread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-openthread) MS function and ExitStatus set to whatever you want.